# What is the most pythonic way to apply a function on and return multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

While using Pandas, I often encounter a case where there is an existing function which takes in multiple arguments and returns multiple values:

```
def foo(val_a, val_b):
    """
    Some example function that takes in and returns multiple values.
    Can be a lot more complex.
    """
    sm = val_a + val_b
    sb = val_a - val_b
    mt = val_a * val_b
    dv = val_a / val_b
    return sm, sb, mt, dv
```

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
df
Out[6]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

What I want is to apply `foo` on `df` with column 0 and 1 as arguments, and put the results into new columns of `df`, **without modifying `foo`**, like this:

```
df_out
Out[7]:
   0  1  su  sb  mt  dv
0  1  2  3   -1  2   0.5
1  3  4  7   -1  12  0.75
2  5  6  11  -1  30  0.833
3  7  8  15  -1  56  0.875
```

What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: If it is just a basic mathematical operation, then for me, the pythonic way is just simply adding the Series. For example, `df['sm'] = df[0] + df[1]` or `df['sb'] = df[0] - df[1]`, and so forth. Hence, it depends on your needs. If it is very customized, then you may end up with `apply` at the end.

Comment: @arnold """Some example function that takes in and returns multiple values. Can be a lot more complex. """

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
cols = ['sm','sb','mt','dv']
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: foo(x[0], x[1]), 1).values.tolist(),columns= cols)
print (df)
   0  1  sm  sb  mt        dv
0  1  2   3  -1   2  0.500000
1  3  4   7  -1  12  0.750000
2  5  6  11  -1  30  0.833333
3  7  8  15  -1  56  0.875000
```

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
cols = ['sm','sb','mt','dv']
df[cols] = pd.concat(foo(df[0], df[1]), axis=1, keys=cols)
print (df)
   0  1  sm  sb  mt        dv
0  1  2   3  -1   2  0.500000
1  3  4   7  -1  12  0.750000
2  5  6  11  -1  30  0.833333
3  7  8  15  -1  56  0.875000
```

Also is possible create new `DataFrame` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) original:

```
cols = ['sm','sb','mt','dv']
df1 = pd.concat(foo(df[0], df[1]), axis=1, keys=cols)
print (df1)
   sm  sb  mt        dv
0   3  -1   2  0.500000
1   7  -1  12  0.750000
2  11  -1  30  0.833333
3  15  -1  56  0.875000

df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print (df)
   0  1  sm  sb  mt        dv
0  1  2   3  -1   2  0.500000
1  3  4   7  -1  12  0.750000
2  5  6  11  -1  30  0.833333
3  7  8  15  -1  56  0.875000
```

Comment: I accept @jezrael 's answer as it is the most comprehensive one.

Comment: However, @spies006 's answer is superior in performance by >30%, which I would use if speed is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df.from_records(foo(df[0], df[1])).T], axis=1)
   0  1     0    1     2         3
0  1  2   3.0 -1.0   2.0  0.500000
1  3  4   7.0 -1.0  12.0  0.750000
2  5  6  11.0 -1.0  30.0  0.833333
3  7  8  15.0 -1.0  56.0  0.875000
```

Speed: 1.13 ms per loop

If you care about speed this is superior to using `apply` and gives your desired output.

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df.from_records(np.vectorize(foo)(df[0], df[1])).T], axis=1)
```

Speed: 728 µs per loop

Answer (score 1):

```
#apply function foo and generate a DF using return values and then merge into existing DF.
merged = pd.merge(df,df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(foo(x[0],x[1])),axis=1),left_index=True,right_index=True)
#change column names.
merged.columns=[0,1,'sm','sb','mt','dv']

merged
Out[1478]: 
   0  1    sm   sb    mt        dv
0  1  2   3.0 -1.0   2.0  0.500000
1  3  4   7.0 -1.0  12.0  0.750000
2  5  6  11.0 -1.0  30.0  0.833333
3  7  8  15.0 -1.0  56.0  0.875000
```